# iOS/C: Convert "integer" into four character string

Tags: ios, c, fourcc

A lot of the constants associated with Audio Session programming are really four-character strings ([Audio Session Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007915-CH6-SW2)). The same applies to the [OSStatus code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007915-CH7a-SW1) returned from functions like `AudioSessionGetProperty`.

The problem is that when I try to print these things out of the box, they look like 1919902568. I can plug that into Calculator and turn on ASCII output and it'll tell me "roch", but there must be a programmatic way to do this.

I've had limited success in one of my C functions with the following block:

```
char str[20];
// see if it appears to be a four-character code
*(UInt32 *) (str + 1) = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(error);
if (isprint(str[1]) && isprint(str[2]) && isprint(str[3]) && isprint(str[4])) {
    str[0] = str[5] = '\'';
    str[6] = '\0';
} else {
    // no, format as integer
    sprintf(str, "%d", (int)error);
}
```

What I want to do is to abstract this feature out of its current function, in order to use it elsewhere. I tried doing

```
char * fourCharCode(UInt32 code) {
    // block
}
void someOtherFunction(UInt32 foo){
    printf("%s\n",fourCharCode(foo));
}
```

but that gives me "à*€/3íT:ê*€/+€/", not "roch". My C fu isn't very strong, but my hunch is that the above code tries to interpret the memory address as a string. Or perhaps there's an encoding issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The type you're talking about is a `FourCharCode`, defined in `CFBase.h`. It's equivalent to an `OSType`. The easiest way to convert between `OSType` and `NSString` is using `NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode()` and `NSHFSTypeCodeFromFileType()`. These functions, unfortunately, aren't available on iOS.

For iOS and Cocoa-portable code, I like [Joachim Bengtsson's](http://thirdcog.eu/) `FourCC2Str()` from his [`NCCommon.h`](http://thirdcog.eu/code/NCCommon.h) (plus a little casting cleanup for easier use):

```
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#if TARGET_RT_BIG_ENDIAN
#   define FourCC2Str(fourcc) (const char[]){*((char*)&fourcc), *(((char*)&fourcc)+1), *(((char*)&fourcc)+2), *(((char*)&fourcc)+3),0}
#else
#   define FourCC2Str(fourcc) (const char[]){*(((char*)&fourcc)+3), *(((char*)&fourcc)+2), *(((char*)&fourcc)+1), *(((char*)&fourcc)+0),0}
#endif

FourCharCode code = 'APPL';
NSLog(@"%s", FourCC2Str(code));
NSLog(@"%@", @(FourCC2Str(code));
```

You could of course throw the `@()` into the macro for even easier use.

Comment: Ooh, that sounds really useful. It gives me an error "Expected expression" out of the box though, so I'll have to come back to this.

Comment: Cleaned up to make it a little easier to use. It returns a char[] rather than a char*, and that seems to confuse things now.

Comment: `NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode` for `1634039412` annoyingly returns a 6-length `"\'aevt\'"` with the single quotes included :/

Answer (score 7):

In Swift you would use this function:

```
func str4 (n: Int) -> String
{
    var s: String = ""
    var i: Int = n

    for var j: Int = 0; j < 4; ++j
    {
        s = String(UnicodeScalar(i & 255)) + s
        i = i / 256
    }

    return (s)
}
```

This func will do the same like above in a third of the time:

```
func str4 (n: Int) -> String
{
    var s: String = String (UnicodeScalar((n >> 24) & 255))
    s.append(UnicodeScalar((n >> 16) & 255))
    s.append(UnicodeScalar((n >> 8) & 255))
    s.append(UnicodeScalar(n & 255))
    return (s)
}
```

The reverse way will be:

```
func val4 (s: String) -> Int
{
    var n: Int = 0
    var r: String = ""
    if (countElements(s) > 4)
    {
        r = s.substringToIndex(advance(s.startIndex, 4))
    }
    else
    {
        r = s + "    "
        r = r.substringToIndex(advance(r.startIndex, 4))
    }
    for UniCodeChar in r.unicodeScalars
    {
        n = (n << 8) + (Int(UniCodeChar.value) & 255)
    }

    return (n)
}
```

Comment: Just to simplify one of your functions [code]func stringValue(unicodeValue: Int) -> String {
    var stringValue = ""
    var value = unicodeValue
    
    for _ in 0..<4 {
         stringValue = String(UnicodeScalar(value & 255)) + stringValue
        value = value / 256
    }
    
    return stringValue
}[\code]

Comment: Another way: extension Int {
    var unicodeStringValue: String {
        
        get {
            var stringValue = ""
            var value = self
            
            for _ in 0..<4 {
                stringValue = String(UnicodeScalar(value & 255)) + stringValue
                value = value / 256
            }
            
            return stringValue
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 4):

```
char str[5];
str[4] = '\0';
long *code = (long *)str;
*code = 1919902568;
printf("%s\n", str);
```

Comment: After figuring out a reverseStr function, this works. I'd really like to get a DRYer solution (like to wrap this in a method), but it serves for now.

Comment: `long *code = (long *)str; *code = 1919902568;` is a strict aliasing violation and invokes undefined behavior.  Additionally, merely creating the pointer `long *code = (long *)str;` can also invoke undefined behavior if any platform-specific alignment requirements are not met - note that the UB is invoked immediately on pointer creation in that case and no dereference is needed to invoke UB.

Answer (score 4):

Integer = 4 bytes = 4 chars. So to convert from integer to char * you can simply write:

```
char st[5] = {0};
st[0] = yourInt & 0xff;
st[1] = (yourInt >> 8) & 0xff;
st[2] = (yourInt >> 16) & 0xff;
st[3] = (yourInt >> 24) & 0xff;
```

To convert it back:

```
yourInt = st[0] | (st[1] << 8) | (st[2] << 16) | (st[3] << 24);
```

Comment: wouldn't it be good to add `st[4] = '\0';` in case someone wants to print the string?

Comment: May seem simple but the approach is wrong. The first character is the highest byte. `#define FourCC2Str(code) (char[5]){(code >> 24) & 0xFF, (code >> 16) & 0xFF, (code >> 8) & 0xFF, code & 0xFF, 0}`

Comment: It is not wrong since most CPUs, including Intel ones, are little-endian nowadays.

Comment: It is unadvisable, because you do not know that st[4] is yours to change. It is OUTSIDE the memory where your FourBytesCode is stored. Remember that these are almost always simple Int32 variables, and not "memory blocks", and this byte you are zeroing could easily be part of another variable or just crash your program immediately.

Comment: @JanRüegg st[4] is already `\0` due to `= {0}` initialization. 
@MottiShneor why st[4] cannot be yours once it is on the stack?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this C function for my audio code ... it might be a tad naive, but it does the job for well enough for me:

```
NSString* fourCharNSStringForFourCharCode(FourCharCode aCode){

char fourChar[5] = {(aCode >> 24) & 0xFF, (aCode >> 16) & 0xFF, (aCode >> 8) & 0xFF, aCode & 0xFF, 0};

NSString *fourCharString = [NSString stringWithCString:fourChar encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

return fourCharString; }
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using a function like this:

```
static NSString * NSStringFromCode(UInt32 code)
{
    UInt8 chars[4];
    *(UInt32 *)chars = code;
    for(UInt32 i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        if(!isprint(chars[i]))
        {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", code];
        }
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%c%c%c", chars[3], chars[2], chars[1], chars[0]];
}
```

This will ensure that you don't end up with some random results for some FourCharCodes that are actual numbers like `kCMPixelFormat_32ARGB = 32`.

Answer (score 3):

In case you're developing for macOS rather than iOS, there's already a built-in function for this in Launch Services.  To get the 4cc as NSString:

```
(__bridge_transfer NSString *)UTCreateStringForOSType(fourccInt)
```

Comment: Same as existing answer by Charlesism.

Comment: There is no answer by anyone with that name, and no answer mentioning UTCreateStringForOSType/()

Comment: He deleted it 10 hours ago. Nevertheless, it is right for macOS, and was of great help to me in writing a macOS application. As his answer rightly said, however, the original question is about iOS, where UTCreateStringForOSType — so your answer suffers from that issue as well.

Comment: This is the best answer so far. reason: it is THE INTENDED function to use, created and maintained by Apple, and so - future-changes-safe. Also, I believe it should be efficient, and its name is descriptive. Been looking for this all over the place

Comment: Sadly Apple has deprecated it in macOS 12. Sigh.

Answer (score 3):

Here are my helper functions I use within test targets:

Swift 5:

```
extension FourCharCode {
    private static let bytesSize = MemoryLayout<Self>.size
    var codeString: String {
        get {
            withUnsafePointer(to: bigEndian) { pointer in
                pointer.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: Self.bytesSize) { bytes in
                    String(bytes: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bytes,
                                                      count: Self.bytesSize),
                           encoding: .macOSRoman)!
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension OSStatus {
    var codeString: String {
        FourCharCode(bitPattern: self).codeString
    }
}

private func fourChars(_ string: String) -> String? {
    string.count == MemoryLayout<FourCharCode>.size ? string : nil
}
private func fourBytes(_ string: String) -> Data? {
    fourChars(string)?.data(using: .macOSRoman, allowLossyConversion: false)
}
func stringCode(_ string: String) -> FourCharCode {
    fourBytes(string)?.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: FourCharCode.self).byteSwapped } ?? 0
}
```

It works for me both on macOS and iOS and closely matches the behaviour of built-in macOS `NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode` and `NSHFSTypeCodeFromFileType`

A couple of gotchas:

1. use `bigEndian` and `byteSwapped`
2. use `macOSRoman` encoding
3. handle long strings by returning 0, as `NSHFSTypeCodeFromFileType`

The difference of above implementation from standard library methods:

1. `NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode` adds extra single quotes around the sting: `NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(OSType(kAudioCodecBadDataError))) == "'bada'"`. I've opted out to just return `bada`
2. it fails to produce strings with `\0` in the middle, like in `NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(kAudioFormatMicrosoftGSM)` should be `ms\01` but returns `'ms`

Answer (score 2):

A more Swifty implementation, working for Swift 4:

```
extension String {
    init(fourCharCode: FourCharCode) {
        let n = Int(fourCharCode)
        var s: String = ""

        let unicodes = [UnicodeScalar((n >> 24) & 255), UnicodeScalar((n >> 16) & 255), UnicodeScalar((n >> 8) & 255), UnicodeScalar(n & 255)]
        unicodes.flatMap { (unicode) -> String? in
            guard let unicode = unicode else { return nil }
            return String(unicode)
        }.forEach { (unicode) in
            s.append(unicode)
        }

        self = s.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
    }
}
```

Which can be used as followed:

```
String(fourCharCode: CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType(charCode))
```

Answer (score 2):

> - Handles different endian architectures
> - iOS and MacOS(*et al*)
> - Easy to understand
> - Resulting string (should be) identical to OSType even with 8-bit characters

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h> // for EndianU32_NtoB
@implementation NSString (FourCC)

+ (NSString *) stringFromFourCC: (OSType) cccc
{
    NSString * result = nil;
    cccc = EndianU32_NtoB(cccc); // convert to network byte order, if needed
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithBytes: &cccc length: sizeof(OSType)];
    result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding]; // lossless 8-bit encoding, could also use NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding
    return result;
}
```

Comment: See preceding text box, and integral comments. If that does not suffice, please ask a specific question.

Comment: I think you could avoid creating NSData wrapper object, and build NSString directly from "bytes" using:   - (nullable instancetype)initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)len encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;

Answer (score 1):

```swift
public extension UInt32 {
    var string: String {
        String([
            Character(Unicode.Scalar(self >> 24 & 0xFF) ?? "?"),
            Character(Unicode.Scalar(self >> 16 & 0xFF) ?? "?"),
            Character(Unicode.Scalar(self >> 8 & 0xFF) ?? "?"),
            Character(Unicode.Scalar(self & 0xFF) ?? "?")
        ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Swift 2.2 version as two extensions:

```
extension String {
    public var fourCharCode:FourCharCode {
        var string = self
        if unicodeScalars.count < 4 {
            string = self + "    "
        }
        string = string.substringToIndex(string.startIndex.advancedBy(4))

        var res:FourCharCode = 0
        for unicodeScalar in string.unicodeScalars {
            res = (res << 8) + (FourCharCode(unicodeScalar) & 255)
        }

        return res
    }
}

extension FourCharCode {
    public var string:String {
        var res = String (UnicodeScalar((self >> 24) & 255))
        res.append(UnicodeScalar((self >> 16) & 255))
        res.append(UnicodeScalar((self >> 8) & 255))
        res.append(UnicodeScalar(self & 255))
        return res
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Swift 3 version of j.s.com's code, cleaned up to eliminate repetition:

```
func debugPrintFourCcCode(_ value: Int) {
  var res = ""

  if value <= 0x28 {
    res = "\(value)"
  } else {
    func add(_ pos: Int) {
      res.append(String(UnicodeScalar((value >> pos) & 255)!))
    }

    add(24)
    add(16)
    add(8)
    add(0)
  }

  NSLog("Code: \(res)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A version for the Mac, but not iOS:

```
extension String {

    init(_ fourCharCode: FourCharCode) { // or `OSType`, or `UInt32`
        self = NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(fourCharCode).trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "'"))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tricksy Swift version:

```
func convert(fileType: OSType) -> String {
    let chars = [24, 16, 8, 0].map { Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(fileType >> $0 & 0xFF)))}
    return String(chars)
}
```

I've tested on Swift 5, but should work on previous Swift versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of my preferred answer above (thanks **pawneebill**)
I save the creation and deallocation of an NSData intermediate object by using a different NSString initializer.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h> // for EndianU32_NtoB
@implementation NSString (FourCC)

+ (NSString *) stringFromFourCC: (OSType) cccc
{
    NSString * result = nil;
    cccc = EndianU32_NtoB(cccc); // convert to network byte order if needed
    result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: &cccc length: sizeof(cccc) encoding: NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding]; // lossless 8-bit encoding
    return result;
}
```

Or, more compact but less explained...

```
+ (NSString *) stringFromFourCC: (OSType) cccc
{
    cccc = EndianU32_NtoB(cccc); // convert to network byte order if needed
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: &cccc length: sizeof(cccc) encoding: NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding]; // lossless 8-bit encoding
}
```