# Find enum label in LLDB

Tags: swift, lldb

I'm writing an audio converter using AudioToolbox on macOS and need a method to cross-reference what these integer enums in C are. My code:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/file.wav") as CFURL

var audioFile: ExtAudioFileRef? = nil
ExtAudioFileOpenURL(url, &audioFile)

var format = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
var propertySize = UInt32(MemoryLayout.stride(ofValue: format))
ExtAudioFileGetProperty(audioFile!, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat, &propertySize, &format)

print(format.mFormatID) // prints 1819304813
```

I went through the header file and print out the keys one by one:

```
(lldb) p kAudioFormatLinearPCM
(AudioFormatID) $R2 = 1819304813
```

So I know it's Linear PCM. Is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: Try print(NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(format.mFormatID)).

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222435/ios-c-convert-integer-into-four-character-string

Comment: `NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode` gave me `'lpcm'`. Somewhat useful but is there a closer match?